# Extended Long Line isn't path-connected; proof

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I know this is a well known result yet I'm having trouble proving it.

The open long line is defined as:

$L = \omega_1 \times [0,1)$ without its minimal element where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal

The extended open long line is:

$L$*$ = \omega_2 \times [0,1)$ without its minimal element, where $\omega_2$ is the successor of $\omega_1$.

Can you give me a hint as to how to prove $L$* isn't path connected, without using any notions of compactness? I know I need to choose points like $\{\{\emptyset\},0\}$ and $\{\omega_1,0\}$ and I thought of using the intermediate value theorem - but then a cardinality argument doesn't suffice.

Comment: Be careful.  Those two points are  (1,0) and (omega_1,0).

Comment: Not an answer but I think it is very interesting that the extended long line is "not path-connected", not because it has some gap or something, but just because it is (somehow) *too long* for any path to reach from one end to the other. This might be more of a flaw of the paths we are considering, than a flaw of $L^*$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a path from a = (1,0) to b = (omega_1,0).
Since the long line is Hausdorff, there is an arc from a to b.
Show the arc is increasing and use that to construct an order
embedding of omega_1 + 1 into [0,1], an impossibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; what do you mean by an arc? Can you reference why an order embedding as such is impossible?

Comment: @Mariah An arc within an Hausdorff space is an injective path.  If f order imbedds omega_1 into R, then {  (f(xi), f(xi+1) | xi < omega_1 } is an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint sets, each of which contains a rational, an impossibility.